# Are there any examples in Adventurers League of Constructs skinned from other creatures?

Tags: dnd-5e, published-adventures, dnd-adventurers-league

When writing Convention Creation Content (CCC) adventures, a variety of [guidelines](http://dndadventurersleague.org/how-do-i-ccc-and-other-questions/) must be met for acceptance. One regards monsters:

> **What monsters can I put in my adventure?** You can choose from creatures
>   in sources published under the Dungeons & Dragons brand such as the
>   Monster Manual or Volo’s Guide to Monsters. **You can modify them in
>   small ways, such as** changing a bandit to an elf bandit using the rules
>   Dungeon Masters Guide, or **saying the party faces a large animated
>   statue, but using the statistics of an ogre reskinned as that statue.**
>   You may not invent new monsters. The stat blocks in the adventure’s
>   appendix must be faithful reproductions of the creature as found in
>   its original product. Minor adjustments should be called out in a
>   sidebar.

Presumably this means that a Construct might be skinned with the stats from a Dire Wolf or other creature.

Have any officially approved Adventurers League adventures (WoTC or CCC)published to date had Constructs skinned with stats from other creatures? If so, what were they?

Answer (score 6):

"[DDAL06-02 The Redemption of Kelvan](http://www.dmsguild.com/product/211249/DDAL0602-The-Redemption-of-Kelvan-5e)" contained a clockwork wyvern construct that had stats based on a regular wyvern.

Answer (score 1):

The Wizards published adventure Tomb of Annihilation does this with clay warriors that use reskinned NPC (gladiator) stats.